# Can't scale a ggplot axis based on min and max values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to scale a ggplot2 axis based off the min and max `cyl` values as shown below. But my code has an error. So I'm here.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n)) + 
  geom_col() +  
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(min(cyl) - 1, max(cyl) + 1, 1)
  )
```

I want my x-axis to extend from two to ten. Why is my code throwing the error:

```
"Error in seq(min(cyl) - 1, max(cyl) + 1, 1) : object 'cyl' not found"
```

Comment: @divibisan sorry typo when typing into StackOverflow, has been fixed now, but the same issue persists, any idea what I did wrong

Comment: Take a look at that answer

Comment: The question at the dupe is the same, but the answer is bad. The right answer should be to use the `expand` argument of `scale_x_continuous`. You want to add 1 unit on each end of the scale? `scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 1))`.

Comment: Yeah, getting on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference column names in `ggplot` objects except inside `aes()` and in a formula in a `facet*` function. But the helper function `expand_scale` is there to help you expand the scales in a more controlled way.

You want to extend the x-scale by 1 unit in each direction, so you should do this:

```
scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 1))
```

See `?scale_x_continuous` and especially `?expand_scale` for details.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `seq` inside the `scale_x_continuous` doesn't get the reference to your data from the pipe functions if you change it to the following, it works fine.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

datas <- mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) 

ggplot(datas, aes(x=cyl, y=n)) + geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(min(datas$cyl) - 1, max(datas$cyl) + 1, 1)
  )
```